# Unit tеsting against protеcted properties

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Ideas how to write good OOP code, SOLID, incapsulation, loose coupling and so lead to

- not using public properties
- use as little getters as possible

Say we have code

```
class Some
{
  protected int $x;
  protected int $y;
 
  public function __construct(int $x, int $y) {
    $this->x = $x;
    $this->y = $y;
  }

  public function swapXY() : void {
    $r = $this->x;
    $this->x = $this->y;
    $this->y = $r;
  }
}
```

Test will not work

```
class SomeTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testSwap() {
        $obj = new Some(5, 6);
        $obj->swapXY();
        $this->assertSame(6, $obj->x);  // ERROR
        $this->assertSame(5, $obj->y);

        
    }
}
```

How can I test Some::swapXY() method  with PHPUnit since PHPUnit 9.0 dropped support methods like assertAttributeSame()?

I am not discussing here testing protected/private methods. Only this situation: We send a signal to object via it's method. Post condition of this work is not some value returned, but some of object properties set to another values.

Using Reflection will help, but why it is considered like so bad idea that it was taken away from testing framework?

The difference with question given as duplicate that : 1) my question about properties not methods 2) that answer is 12 years old, and that is  epoch for IT.

Comment: Right now, that object is useless. It can store two variables and swap them, but with no other methods there's never a way to do anything with it. What other public (or protected) methods does the "real" one have? That's where you should be aiming your unit tests.

Comment: I thought so too, but X and Y may be used by child classes.

Comment: That object is example, to make question practical.  I am not asking whether it is useless or not but how to test it

Comment: Why the question is closed with giving a link to answer which 12 years old?
Has nothing changed for 12 years in IT ?

Comment: We can't tell you how to test it if that's the extent of the example. If the object is intended to be extended then show us how. Your unit tests should focus on the interface presented by the object (or yes, any child classes). Test behaviour, not implementation. Right now this object has no output, so you won't be able to test it. If you really want to examine the inner workings of it, then Reflection is an option (as you've said).

Comment: @iainn what if we add method to class - 
pow() {return $this->x ** $this->y;} -
Object is useful this way, does some work. We are not going to extend it.
Do you propose to test swap() method use the results of pow() method ?

Comment: Yes, adding a method that uses x and y, makes the example class do something. More so, the `pow()` method gives another result when x and y are swapped.

Comment: There are additions to that duplicate from last year, the principle of the question is still the same - but answers have moved on.

Comment: Yes - if you add a public `pow` method then you would test its result. Initialise with 2, 3 and test that the result is 8 (2 ^ 3). Call swap. Test that the result is 9 (3 ^ 2). The point is that your class has to actually do something for you to test it (unless, again, you want to dig into the internals using Reflection/etc). How does the rest of your application use this class? Aim your tests at that coupling.

Comment: it just if there is refactoring and something changes in pow() my tests will break, since they have unnecessary dependence on it for the tests sake

Comment: You're testing both the `pow()` and `swapXY()` methods. Both should function properly for the test to pass. I don't think you want to propose not to test the `pow()` method?

Comment: I need to test pow() but in it's own test. Perform some one task and do it well.
Test which tryes to figure out the way to perform it's tasks looks too complicated and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Test this logic as a part of the public class API. X and Y must be used somewhere in some public method. Probably in a child class. Test it instead.

Comment: What a crooked way. 
Test will concentrate not at testing the particular method but how to figure out values it needs from some other methods, inside methods.
I thought tests should be easy readable.